# Using ViewOverlay

Tags: android, overlay

I want to show an animation when a certain action happens in my application. This animation shall overlay a listview. From what I understand, this should be possible with a ViewOverlay, but I'm struggling with getting the basics to work currently.

What I tried is to simply display a vector drawable that I already have on top of my list view. In my activity's onCreate() I have the following code:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backspace);
d.setBounds(0,0, listview.getMeasuredWidth(), listview.getMeasuredHeight());
listview.getOverlay().add(d);
```

Shouldn't this display my drawable somewhere on top of my listview? For me  it doesn't - what am I missing?

Comment: Where are you calling that, exactly? Have you checked the returned dimensions of the `ListView` there?

Comment: I did it in my activities onCreate() method. You're right it seems the list wasn't ready yet. I moved the code to a onclick handler and it works

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspected. `View`s aren't laid out yet in `onCreate()`, so their dimensions will all be zero there.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: `listview.post(() -> listview.getOverlay().add(d));`

There was no layout pass happen yet at onCreate so your views are not measured yet. Defer overlay operation into `post` method - your view will have been measured at that time so you will have correct values to use.